# Multiplying one-dimensional arrays with matrices using Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I was wondering why this doesn't work with Eigen:

```
MatrixXd A = MatrixXd::Random(3, 10);
Array<double, 1, Dynamic> x = Array<double, 1, Dynamic>::Random(10);
MatrixXd y = x.matrix() * A.transpose();
```

while this works:

```
MatrixXd A = MatrixXd::Random(3, 10);
Array<double, 1, Dynamic> x = Array<double, 1, Dynamic>::Random(10);
MatrixXd y = MatrixXd(x) * A.transpose();
```

and this also works:

```
MatrixXd A = MatrixXd::Random(3, 10);
ArrayXXd x = Array<double, 1, Dynamic>::Random(10);
MatrixXd y = x.matrix() * A.transpose();
```

My compiler gives me the following error message for the first example (clang-500.2.79):

code/Eigen/src/Core/ArrayWrapper.h:178:56: error: **cannot initialize return object of type 'ScalarWithConstIfNotLvalue *' (aka 'double *') with an rvalue of type 'const Scalar *' (aka 'const double *')** inline ScalarWithConstIfNotLvalue* data() { return m_expression.data(); }

Comment: Works for me with both gcc and clang, with both Eigen 3.1 and 3.2. Please provide a self-contained example with the Eigen version.

Comment: The version of Eigen I used was 3.1.2. I downloaded a more recent version (3.1.4) and now it compiles without problems. Thanks ggael.